# How can i dismiss a apple watch alert with swift program after 5 second?

Tags: swift4, watchos-4

I defined a function (which consists of 2 buttons) to display an alert. I am looking for a solution to dismiss the message automatically after `x seconds`. Can anybody help me with that?